# why does supervisor 3.3 still setup python2.7

Tags: python-3.x, supervisord

While setting up supervisor on an Ubuntu machine via `apt-get install supervisor`, I noticed it setting up `python2.7` as part of the installation.

I have 2 questions -

1. Why `supervisor` 3.3.1 which is relatively very new still using
   `python2.7`? The old version was not present on my system till `apt-get`
   installed it as a sub-dependency.
2. What can I do to have `supervisor` depend on `python3.x`?

Comment: Note that `master` on github has python3 support -- but the 4.x release of supervisor has not occurred yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supervisor currently does not support Python 3.  See the [platform requirements](http://supervisord.org/introduction.html#platform-requirements):

> Supervisor is known to work with Python 2.4 or later but will not work under any version of Python 3.